# How do I know if my MFC Application use COM / OLE?

Tags: windows, mfc

I come from Win7 to Win10 and recently ran in an "Improper argument error" by opening an file.
The error occurs very rare and randomly.
No further info or call stack info are provided. I had do search deep in MFC code. The DocManager opens the document and then calls `CDocument::SetPathName(..,TRUE)` to add the current file to the recent file list too.

It seems this function use now an OLE/COM function.

```
void CRecentFileList::Add(LPCTSTR lpszPathName, LPCTSTR lpszAppID)
{
  :
  :
  Add(lpszPathName);

  HRESULT hr = S_OK;
  CComPtr<IShellItem> psi = NULL;

  hr = _AfxSHCreateItemFromParsingName(lpszPathName, NULL, IID_IShellItem, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&psi));
  ENSURE(SUCCEEDED(hr));   // Remark Tom: This throws an AfxInvalidException()
 
}
```

hr ErrorCode is -2147221008, which means `CoInitialize` has not been called.

I am surprised, because I never used COM / OLE Stuff.

Do overcome this error, I must add `AfxOleInit()` in `InitInstance`.

My question is, how Do I know in advance if my application needs to use OLE / COM?

Additional question, do I have any drawback if I use COM / OLE in my application. (memory & speed)?

Comment: With so much of the Windows API surface exposed through COM it's a fair guess that any non-trivial Windows application is going to use COM at some point. Initializing a thread into a COM apartment isn't free. Once done there isn't any runtime overhead. It's unlikely that registering threads for COM is going to exhibit any observable performance degradation. Note though that COM is initialized per thread. A single initialization call in `InitInstance` is only going to register your UI thread.

Comment: P.S.: Your MFC application has probably always used COM, yet didn't fail even though it should have (see [Why does CoCreateInstance work even though my thread never called CoInitialize? The curse of the implicit MTA](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130419-00/?p=4613) for details). Maybe something changed in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how Do I know in advance if my application needs to use OLE / COM?

MFC applications are supposed to always initialize OLE/COM, specifically with a concurrency model of STA (single thread apartment). This is done automatically in the wizard-generated templates, otherwise it must be done explicitly in user's code. From the [CWinApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinapp-class?view=vs-2019#initinstance) documentation:

> *MFC applications must be initialized as single threaded apartment (STA).*
>
> *If you call CoInitializeEx in your InitInstance override, specify COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED (rather than COINIT_MULTITHREADED).*

Having OLE/COM always initialized to STA also avoids [*the curse of the implicit MTA*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130419-00/?p=4613) mentioned by @IInspectable in a comment.